# Normal Distribution - Word questions

Tags: normal-distribution

I am having trouble with the below question"

The time spent waiting for a prescription to be prepared at a chemist's shop is normally distributed with mean 15 minutes and standard deviation 2.8 minutes.  Find the probability that the waiting time is:

a) more then $20$ minutes.

So is what I am doing correct?

t ~ N(15,7.84) 
P(t > 20)
P(Z> 20-15 / 2.8)
= 0.03707

Is this correct?

Thanks!

Comment: $(20-15)/2.8$ (parantheses added). I didn't check the outcome (I dislike tables).

Comment: drhab is correct, and your numerical answer is correct.

Comment: @probablyme and drhab thanks!  any reason why the mark scheme states $0.0367$ ?  Thanks!

Comment: I used a calculator. Answer sheets tend to use values from a table, and tables values are usually rounded. Also, they might have rounded $(20-15)/2.8$. Also, formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).